# Установка несколько cookie node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Надо установить две cookie, при отправке запроса на сервер. Устанавливаю так:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('name1', 'value1', {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 60,
    path: '/'
}));

res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('name2', 'value2', {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 60 * 2,
    path: '/'
}));
```

Но в результате в куку записывается только последний (name2). Как правильно записать и name1 и name2?

Comment: Используй res.cookie

Comment: Пробовл -> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: res.cookie is not a function

Comment: или `res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [cookie.serialize(), cookie.serialize()].join('; '))`

Comment: Так ошибок нет но и куки не устанавливает

Comment: А, так у вас не express (надо же :). Тогда массив, как выше, только не нужно его join-ить,  оставьте массивом

Comment: Да, без join все ок. Мое почтение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setheader_name_value

> Sets a single header value for headers object. If this header already exists in the to-be-sent headers, its value will be replaced. **Use an array of strings here to send multiple headers with the same name.**

Нужно просто положить все куки одним массивом

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
  cookie.serialize('name1', 'value1', {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 60,
    path: '/'
  }),
  cookie.serialize('name2', 'value2', {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 60 * 2,
    path: '/'
  })
]);
```